# How to set JSpinner as non editable?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am creating time picker using a `JSpinner`. The text inside the `JSpinner` is editable. But I want to set the `JSpinner` as non editable, because there is the chance to give an invalid value. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you comment on jfpoilpret's answer if it helped or not? And if it did, accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following:

```
JSpinner spinner = ...;
((DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
```

This should work as long as you didn't change the spinner editor yourself by calling `spinner.setEditor(...)`.

Tell us if this helps.

Comment: I modified your code,It works Fine. JSpinner ampm=new JSpinner(); JFormattedTextField ampmspin=((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)ampm.getEditor()).getTextField(); 
ampmspin.setEditable(false);
Thank you very much.........

Comment: I had to add this after I set the spinner's list model. Then it worked.

Comment: When I try this, the spinner can still be edited by click the arrow!

Answer (score 13):

A bit shorter:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DefaultEditor(spinner));
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try this, the spinner can still be edited by click the arrow! – yelliver

You can try setting the step to 0:

`mySpinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(yourDefaultDisplayValue, 
                    minValue, maxValue, step));`

You can explore the other spinner models and do the same trick I guess.