# Java: manually editing of JSpinner value

Tags: java, jspinner, arrows

I am trying to make a date setter by JSpinner:

```
    //got current date
`   Date now = new Date();
    //got"Date maxDate" from somewhere

    SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(now, now, maxDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    JComponent editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");`
```

As you can see, date has boundries: from current date to some max date; and I want to make sure that that input (which invokes by Set button, see picture below):

```
spinner.getValue();
```

will be inside that zone. If user uses only arrow, it's ok: they don't allow to go beyond boundries.

But there is an issue: user can manually (without using arrows) set date:
[image]

Question: how can I forbid to make date change manually, and allow do it only by arrows?

(Bonus question: why can't I change date by arrows from the start (first I should change it manually, then it is available to make change by arrows).)

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902101/how-to-set-jspinner-as-non-editable